# Create Database in PervasiveSQL from Command Line

Tags: pervasive, pervasive-sql

How do I create a database in PervasiveSQL using the command line.

I know how to do it via Control Center, but I would rather create it via the command line. I am working to automate the standup of a PervasiveSQL box for a project I am working on. I have the server install happening silently and I am adjusting the Server Configuration using a RegKey import.

Now i just need to script the creation of the database. The new database will use existing database files which are already copied to the server.

In the documentation I am using [found here](https://www.pervasive.com/Portals/55/documents/psqlv11/PSQLv11SP3_Users_Guide.pdf): there is a utility called dbMaint (page 264) which seems like it would do the job, but I do not seem to have that tool on my server.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dbMaint is only provided for PSQL on Linux.  There is a way to write a utility using the Distributed Tuning Interface (DTI) or Distributed Tuning Object (DTO) to create the database.  I can't link to the PSQL documentation but there is a PSQL_DTI_GUIDE.pdf and PSQL_DTO_Guide.pdf in the PSQL v11 documentation download that describes how to use those APIs.

Found a C# sample I put together a while back.  The Pervasive DTO library will need to be added as a reference.  It's a COM object.  The simple sample is:

```
using System;
using DTOLib;

namespace dtoTest
{
    class Class1
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string compName = null;
            string userName = null;
            string password = null;
            string dbname = null;
            string ddflocation = null;
            string datalocation = null;
            dtoDbFlags dbflags = DTOLib.dtoDbFlags.dtoDbFlagDefault;

            DTOLib.dtoResult result;
            if (args.LongLength < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid options.\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Usage: dtoDBN.EXE <computername> <username> <password> <dbname> <ddf location> <data location> <DBFlage>");
                Console.WriteLine("NOTE: locations must be relative to the computer where the PSQL engine is running.");
                Console.WriteLine("DB Flags must be passed as integer in this example with these values:  ");
                Console.WriteLine(" P_DBFLAG_BOUND =  1;  (* bound database - must have P_DBFLAG_CREATE_DDF too *)");
                Console.WriteLine(" P_DBFLAG_RI = 2; (*relational integrity *)");
                Console.WriteLine(" P_DBFLAG_CREATE_DDF = 4; (*create ddf flag *)");
                Console.WriteLine(" P_DBFLAG_NA = 2147483648; (*not applicable *)");
                Console.WriteLine(" P_DBFLAG_DEFAULT = (P_DBFLAG_BOUND or P_DBFLAG_RI); ");

                return;
            }
            if (args.LongLength == 7)
            {
                compName = args[0].ToString();
                userName = args[1].ToString();
                password = args[2].ToString();
                dbname = args[3].ToString();
                ddflocation = args[4].ToString();
                datalocation = args[5].ToString();
                dbflags = (dtoDbFlags)Convert.ToInt32(args[6]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Create Pervasive Database using DTO and C#");
            DtoSession mDtoSession = new DTOLib.DtoSession();
            try
            {
                result = mDtoSession.Connect(compName, userName, password);
                if (result != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error connecting to server.  Error code:");
                }
                else
                {
                    //Create a Database name here.  
                    DtoDatabase db = new DtoDatabase();
                    db.Name = dbname;
                    db.DdfPath = ddflocation;
                    db.DataPath = datalocation;
                    db.Flags = dbflags;
                    result = mDtoSession.Databases.Add(db);
                    if (result !=0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Error creating the datbase ({0}).  Error code: {1}", dbname, result.ToString()));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Database ({0}) created. ", dbname));

                    }

                    result = mDtoSession.Disconnect();
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e1.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but the answer I was expecting none-the-less. My next question is, can I use that tool from a Linux machine to create a DB on a Windows machine?

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it does not appear that you can use it to create remote DB Names.  I used to have a small sample using DTI / DTO, let me see if I can find it.

Comment: were you ever able to locate that example using DTI\DTO?

Comment: Added the sample I found using DTO and C#.

Comment: Look at you being awesome! I'll let you know how it works, it definitely looks quite self explanatory. Thanks again so much.